# Vanilla Javascript Formbuilder

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm looking for a formbuilder creator made in Javascript that doesn't require React/Node.js to use it.
Something like this:
https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder

but it uses react. There is a way to use it even without React?
What I'm lookign for is a formbuilder that create a JSON schema and after that use that schema to let user submit that form.

I found [AlpacaJS](http://www.alpacajs.org/) for form creation based on schema previusly created

Answer (score 0):

Using the FormBuilder jquery plugin in this library:
https://formbuilder.online/docs/formBuilder/demos/react/
in react (and a few other platforms), you can let admins visually create forms which result in JSON formatted schema that can be extracted using the onSave event:

```
$(this.fb.current).formBuilder({ formData,
  onSave:(event,form_schema)=> // save to server (form_schema)
})
```

example of form generation at:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formbuilder-react-rwv60

and then use the FormRender plugin of the same library to render the form for end users using the generated form_schema:

```
$('form', $formContainer).formRender({
      formData: [  ... form_schema from server ]
})
```

example of form rendering at:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJdGmK?editors=0010